# Rotate through Shadowsocks proxy via Python

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I have a python code that would need to make use of various ShadowSocks proxy server that I have set up in order to use the IP of those servers.

Say for example I would like to use:

```
1.1.1.1:5678
2.2.2.2:5678
3.3.3.3:5678
```

i.e., all these servers have the same remote port and the local ports are all 1080.

My preference is to have the 3 proxies to rotate randomly so that each time I send a urlopen() request (in urllib2), my code randomly connect to one of the proxies and send the request via that proxy, and disconnect when the request is complete.

The IP could be hard coded or could be stored in some config files.

The problem is at the moment, all the sample online that I have found seems all require the connection to be pre-established and the Python code should simply use whatever that is on localhost:1080 instead of actively making connections.

I am just wondering if anyone could lend me a helping hand to accomplish this in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/urllib2.py) of urllib2, you can see that when a default opener is installed, it is really just takes an object with an `open` method.  So you really just need to create an object whose `open` method returns a random opener.  Something like the following (untested) should work:

```
import urllib2
import random

class RandomOpener(object):
    def __init__(self, ip_list)
        self.ip_list = ip_list

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        proxy = random.choice(self.ip_list)
        handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://' + proxy})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
        return opener(*args, **kwargs)

my_opener = RandomOpener(['1.1.1.1:5678',
                          '2.2.2.2:5678',
                          '3.3.3.3:5678'])

urllib2.install_opener(my_opener)
```